Done miRNA sequencing from animal tissue & have 1 control sample in duplicates 1 treatment group as test. In PCA plot clustering is not there
I have done miRNA sequencing from animal tissue and have control sample in duplicates . Like wise one treatment group as test. In PCA plot clustering is not there. There is very randomness. Is it normal to have such plots. Is it can be shown in publications?

Please show the PCA plot, and explain further your experimental design. Do you mean two control samples and one treatment sample, i.e. only 3 dots that are visible on the PCA plot?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
